# How to share setup between LyX users

Tags: lyx

I am collaborating with other writers, and my LyX settings have been specialized to include PlantUML re: [I want to embed plantuml diagram into lyx document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154154/i-want-to-embed-plantuml-diagram-into-lyx-document).

Is there a way I can share this set-up with other LyX users easily?

I had a similar trouble when I upgraded from LyX 2.1.x to LyX 2.2 (I had to re-define all the settings by hand and it's quite tedious). It would be great to know how to "share" these configuration settings.

Comment: Which operating system are you on? On Ubuntu, the LyX settings are saved in /home/username/.lyx/
My first attempt would be to copy that folder and see if that's sufficient.