# LyX PlantUML with !include directives

Tags: lyx, convert

I'm aware of the process of embedding PlantUML into LyX.

([I want to embed plantuml diagram into lyx document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154154/i-want-to-embed-plantuml-diagram-into-lyx-document))

However, I need additional .plantuml files to be copied to LyX temp dir, so that I can work with plantuml's !include directives.

I tried to set a copier: python -tt $$s/scripts/ext_copy.py $$i $$o

Apparently, LyX is not calling this copier (only one .plantuml file in the temp directory, not the included files).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.